# How to fail Python package build on any test failure?

Tags: python, build

I am building a simple Python package. I have configured it with a `pyproject.toml` file. The package source tree has a `tests/` directory with some tests based on the `unittest` module.

I assumed that running `python -m build .` would cause the tests in `tests/` to be run and the package build to fail if any of the tests in `tests/` fail. That did not happen.

Is there a Python build system (e.g., Poetry, Hatchling, setuptools) that supports the automatic running of the tests in `tests/` and *fails* the package build if any of the tests fail? If so, how do I configure that build system to do this?